# Relating database records based on time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have would like to group rows based on loosely understood business rules

I have appointment data in the following format.

- The appointment book is organised in 5 minute intervals (see the *Appointment Time*). Some appointments will take longer periods where multiples of 5 minute slots will be used to make up the whole appointment.
- Some appointments are linked into *Client ID*, whereas others are not.
- All appointments will have the last name and first name in the Appointment info e.g. Project meeting :Taylor, James

Appointment Table looks like this

```
ID| AppointmentTime         | Appointment                           |Client ID
23| 2019-09-30 09:15:00.000 | Project meeting :Taylor, James        | NULL  
34| 2019-09-30 09:20:00.000 | Project meeting :Taylor, James        | NULL
35| 2019-09-30 09:25:00.000 | Project meeting :Taylor, James        | NULL
36| 2019-09-30 10:25:00.000 | Pre sales : Hayes, John               | 2
47| 2019-09-30 10:30:00.000 | Project meeting :Manning, Richard     |425
50| 2019-09-30 14:30:00.000 | Closure meeting :Kuruvita, Peter      | NULL
```

Client Table looks like this

```
ID  | Last Name | First Name 
2   | Hayes     | John               
425 | Manning   |Richard
3   | Taylor    | James
```

I want to be able to group appointments based on the below rules

- all appointment slots with the same Client ID with adjacent slots belong to the same appointment
- where there are no client IDs, all appointment slots with the same Last Name and First Name combination  with adjacent slots belong to  the same appointment. The names should be associated with Client table records where possible
- Some Clients wont have records in the Client Table yet. In this has NULL client ID should be returned

  - There are appointments created for clients who existing in the client table but the receptionists may not link them initially.

Expected results look like this

```
ClientID |Clint Name            |Appointment Start      | Appointment End        | Appointment Destail
NULL     |Peter  Kuruvita       |2019-09-30 14:30:00.000|2019-09-30 14:34:00.000 |Closure meeting
3        |James Taylor          |2019-09-30 09:15:00.000|2019-09-30 09:29:00.000 |Project meeting 
2        |John  Hayes           |2019-09-30 10:25:00.000|2019-09-30 10:29:00.000 |Pre sale  
425      |Richard Manning       |2019-09-30 10:30:00.000|2019-09-30 10:34:00.000 |Project meeting
```

Could you please help with a SQL statement or snippets for different parts so that I can piece them together?

The implementation is in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2).

Comment: I don't understand why you are trying to impute client names for `NULL` values.  That makes the SQL query more akin to reading minds.

Comment: What does your attempt look like? What have you tried?

Comment: @nicomp, The scenario above replicates a problem in a different domain. I have gotten something that does max and min bsaed on group by on Client ID.. But obviously thats not enough

Comment: @GordonLinoff very valid observation But unfortunately this is the data I need to work with. The explaination from the business is that appointments after expected to be linked to Clients at a later stage. However this is not always guaranteed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the tables based on adjacent slots and get the *known* client names using the difference of row-numbers approach for gaps-and-islands.

```
select clientid,
       (firstname + ' ' + lastname) as name,
       min(appointment_start),
       max(appointment_end)
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (order by appointment_start) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by clientid order by appointment_start) as seqnum_c             
      from appointment a
     ) a left join
     clients c
     on a.clientid = c.id
group by (seqnum - seqnum_c), a.clientid, c.lastname, c.firstname;
```

Note:  This assumes that adjacent slots for the same client are the same appointment.  If you want to split those, you really need to upgrade your database to a supported version of SQL Server, so you can use `lag()` and other functionality.

For your sample data, you could also just use the appointment name:

```
select clientid,
       (firstname + ' ' + lastname) as name,
       min(appointment_start),
       max(appointment_end)
from appointment a left join
     clients c
     on a.clientid = c.id
group by a.appointment, a.clientid, c.lastname, c.firstname;
```